# How can I generate an html report with k6?

Tags: k6

I'm using grafana and influxdb with k6 for load testing, but I have a usecase where I'll need offline access to the grafana dashboard (or something similar). Does k6, or grafana, have a way to export an html report?

thanks,
jas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k6 itself does not provide that, but you could use the Sharing Options from Grafana: http://docs.grafana.org/reference/sharing/

Or you can use this project to generate a PDF version of the dashboard: https://github.com/IzakMarais/reporter